# Using setInterval to iterate through google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, setinterval, google-sheets-api, tabletop.js

I have 4 rows in a google spreadsheet and want to iterate through them 1 at a time every 1 hour. This code currently works but posts all four at the same time. How can I 1 every hour and make it continuous?

```
require('console-stamp')(console, {
    pattern: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss.l'
});

var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./dmconfig');
var Tabletop = require('tabletop');

var bot = new Twit(config);
var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1234567/edit?usp=sharing';

var link = () => {
    Tabletop.init({
        key: spreadsheetUrl,
        callback(data, tabletop) {
            data.forEach(d => {
                var status = d.tweetMsg + ' ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + ' ' + d.userURL + ' via @AlDerbyshireG';
                console.log(status)
                bot.post('statuses/update', {
                    status
                },
                (err, response, data) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) }
                    else { console.log('Post success!') }
                });
            });
        },
        simpleSheet: true
    });
}

link()
setInterval(link, 1000 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: Can you post the results to make easier the analisis?

Comment: `link` posts all rows of your spreadsheet because you explicitly told it to: `data.forEach( d =>`. If you want to only access a particular index, then you're going to have to feed state to your server, so it knows which row to use.

Answer (score 0):

Per TableTop documentation (literally in the [readme of the repo](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop#callback)), with `simpleSheet: true` you feed your callback function an array of rows from the first sheet of the workbook.

Your code:

```
callback: (data, tabletop) => {
  data.forEach(d =>
```

thus instructs every row on that sheet to be processed.

To call a function for only one row per execution of `callback`, you need to define some other scoped variable - let's call it `rowIndex`. You should initialize this variable when your bot server loads, and then increment and bounds-check it in `callback`.

```
var rowIndex = 0;

var link = () => {
    Tabletop.init({
        key: spreadsheetUrl,
        callback(data, tabletop) {
            if (!data.length) { return; } // Guard against empty spreadsheet
            // Wrap around here, in case new messages were added or deleted since the last invocation.
            rowIndex = rowIndex % data.length;
            var d = data[rowIndex];
            /**
             * Code to call for just this array element `d` (read: row)
             */
            // Increment the state variable so next call is a different row.
            ++rowIndex;
        }, // End callback definition
        simpleSheet: true
   });
};
```